# Combine multiple maven project into 1 war

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have maven structure like this:

```
Parent Module
|--Backend services module (Spring) 
|--Web module (angularjs)
```

When I ran them as separate war files everything is working fine.
But what i want to do is to build and run them as a single .war file.

So I made web module to package as war, and gave him a dependency of backend jar. When I run them on tomcat, web-module is running fine, but Spring service (backend) doesn't work at all. When I start backend service module alone i get this in logs "INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext" and so on.. But this doesn't happen when backend is dependency in another project.

Main web.xml and spring context.xml files are located in the backend module.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: how the Web is connected to the Backend? AJAX calls?

Comment: yes, using ajax and rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Main web.xml and spring context.xml files are located in the backend
>   module."

You mentioned that Backend is a JAR now, so it cannot contains web.xml (under WEB-INF). The Web module is the one that should contain the webapp (including web.xml) and initialize Spring etc.

It seems to me that they both should be the same WAR. You can use the Backend (if it is already a WAR that contains web.xml), and add it all the HTMLs/JSs from Web.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And i already thought about it, but is it okay, that spring initializing stuff will be in separate project?

Comment: Maybe it is better to do opposite way, so the backend module will generate war file, and in generating process it will copy angularjs stuff in webapp/ folder?

Comment: it seems to me that they both should be the same WAR. You can use the Backend, and add it all the HTMLs/JSs from Web. and no, the spring init should not be a separate project. it should be on the WAR.

Comment: yea... seems like it's not a good thing to separate this 2 modules... easier to make them as one module..